# How can I create a subquery, of a subquery, in order to get the Count() of rows, but only display the newest row?Max()

Tags: sql-server

I have a query, which is pretty complex with several joints, and I have it return all messages for a user, as well as the most recent post to that message (that is the max(id) part on messageposts). But I also want to display the total number of posts for a particular message. I don't want to pull all the messages, but just get the count() of rows.

Here is my query, which right now works, WITHOUT the count part:

```
SELECT recipients.readmessage, messages.id AS id, messages.subject, messages.createdat AS messagecreated, messages.userid AS originalposterid, messages.usershortname AS opname, messageposts.id AS messagepostid, messageposts.usershortname AS repliername, messageposts.userid AS replierid, messageposts.updatedat AS messagepostcreated, userpictures.id AS pictureid, userpictures.createdat AS picturedate, userpictures.name AS picname, users.sex 
    FROM recipients 
        INNER JOIN messages ON recipients.messageid = messages.id 
        AND messages.deletedat IS NULL 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN messageposts
            ON messageposts.id =
                 (
                 // HERE IS WHERE I WANT A COUNT//
                 SELECT  max(id) 
                 FROM    messageposts
                 WHERE   messageid = messages.id
                 AND messageposts.deletedat IS NULL
                 )
                INNER JOIN users ON messageposts.userid = users.id 
                AND users.deletedat IS NULL 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN userpictures 
                    ON userpictures.id =
                             (
                             SELECT  max(id)
                             FROM    userpictures
                             WHERE   userid = users.id
                             AND userpictures.deletedat IS NULL
                             )

    WHERE ( recipients.userid = #currentuser.id# ) 
    AND ( recipients.deletedat IS NULL ) 
    ORDER BY recipients.readmessage ASC,messageposts.updatedat DESC,messages.createdat DESC,userpictures.createdat DESC
```

The part that I need to insert is this:

```
(
SELECT COUNT(id) as totalposts
FROM    messageposts
WHERE   messageid = messages.id
)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
(
 SELECT  max(id) 
 FROM       
    (
    SELECT COUNT(id) as totalposts
    FROM    messageposts
    WHERE   messageid = messages.id
    )
    messageposts
 WHERE      messageid = messages.id
 AND messageposts.deletedat IS NULL
 )
```

But this gave me an **ambiguous column name** error. I tried changing it to this:

```
(
 SELECT  max(id) 
 FROM       
    (
    SELECT COUNT(id) as totalposts
    FROM    messageposts
    WHERE   messageposts.messageid = messages.id
    )
    messageposts
 WHERE   messageposts.messageid = messages.id
 AND messageposts.deletedat IS NULL
 )
```

But then I get **invalid column name** messageid.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: That query is awesome. You should definitely consider breaking it into views or CTEs - or both.

Comment: You are getting invalid column name because you have SELECT max(id) but because you have aliased the id column it should be SELECT max(totalposts)

Comment: @DaveSexton that's still not it, even with your suggestion I'm getting invalid column name messageid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the way you are linking to `messageposts` to a subquery:

Old:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN messageposts
    ON messageposts.id =
             (
             // HERE IS WHERE I WANT A COUNT//
             SELECT  max(id) 
             FROM    messageposts
             WHERE   messageid = messages.id
             AND messageposts.deletedat IS NULL
             )
```

New:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        messageid AS postmessageid
        ,max(id) AS LatestPost
        ,count(id) AS TotalPosts
    FROM messageposts
    WHERE deletedat IS NULL
    GROUP BY messageid
    ) PostsOnMessage
ON messages.id = PostsOnMessage.postmessageid
```

Then, you can add `LatestPost` and `TotalPosts` to your fields above.

Comment: I tried this and got: The multi-part identifier "messageposts.userid" could not be bound. I changed, INNER JOIN users ON messageposts.userid = users.id to INNER JOIN users ON PostsOnMessage.userid = users.id and got invalid column name userid.

Comment: I don't have your database, so it is difficult to test the SQL. Basically you make one query to pull the most recent post ID for each message and the total posts, then grab the user ID and picture for that message. Add that as a subquery to your main report.